# MYSQL and PHP group results by

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I will like to display the following database in various html table group by Comp.

```
TeamA         TeamB             Comp
Kenya     Namibia       Africa   World Cup - Qual
Zimbabwe      Mozambique       Africa World Cup - Qual
Coventry City Colchester Utd   England - League One 
Bray Wanderers UCD League Of   Ireland - Premier Division
Dundalk    Drogheda United  League Of Ireland - Premier Division
```

example table 1

```
Comp: Africa World Cup - Qual
Kenya     Namibia
Zimbabwe  Mozambique
```

Example table 2

```
England - League One
Coventry City Colchester Utd
```

etc.

I tried

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Comp) as Comp 
  FROM database 
 Group By Comp`
```

but no luck.

Comment: can you please update your table and query in here : http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: hey what is your query! you sql statement is wrong , we select from table not database, and you are concatenating that column in which you have applied groupby

Comment: You'd need to fetch every row from the db, order by *comp* and add grouping using php. Basic principle is [explained here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/96215-grouping-in-php-from-a-mysql-query-result/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
SELECT comp,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(TeamA, '|', TeamB)) details
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY comp
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| comp                                 | details                                    |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| Africa World Cup - Qual              | Kenya|Namibia,Zimbabwe|Mozambique          |
| England - League One                 | Coventry City|Colchester Utd               |
| League Of Ireland - Premier Division | Bray Wanderers|UCD,Dundalk|Drogheda United |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9190/1)** demo

If needed you can change delimiters both in `CONCAT()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` from comma `,` and pipe `|` respectively. 
You can easily `explode()` details values while iterating over the result set.

Simplified php part using PDO might look like this

```php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'userpwd');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);


$sql = "SELECT comp,
               GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(TeamA, '|', TeamB)) details
               FROM table1
         GROUP BY comp";

$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$query = null;
$db = null;

foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['comp'] . '</br>';
    $details = explode(',', $row['details']);
    foreach($details as $detail) {
        list($teama, $teamb) = explode('|', $detail);
        echo $teama . ' - ' .$teamb . '</br>';
    }
    echo '</br>';
}
```

Output:

```
Africa World Cup - Qual
Kenya - Namibia
Zimbabwe - Mozambique

England - League One
Coventry City - Colchester Utd

League Of Ireland - Premier Division
Bray Wanderers - UCD
Dundalk - Drogheda United
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a database design problem. Do I understand that your output is to display games in a certain competition? So team A plays against team B in competition C?

You should create more than 2 tables I think.

- Table A: containing all your teams.
- Table B containing all    competitions (because probably a team could 
  participate in more than    one competition).
- Table C to join teams   in competitions.
- Table D to  hold games in a certain competition.

In table D we only link records from table C. Reason is to prevent a team playing in a competition that it is not participating in.

So :

```
Table A (Teams) contains columns (idTeam INT, Teamname VARCHAR 50)
Table B (Competitions) contains columns (idComp INT, Competitionname VARCHAR 50)
Table C (TeamCompetitions) contains columns (idTeam INT, idComp INT)
Table D (Games) contains columns (idTeamCompA INT, idTeamCompB INT, idComp INT)
```

Then the query isn't that hard:

```
SELECT 
  TeamA.Teamname as teamA,
  TeamB.Teamname as teamB,
  comp.Competitionname as competition
FROM 
  Games 
     JOIN TeamCompetitions AS compTeamA ON compTeamA.idTeamCompetition = Games.idTeamCompA
     JOIN Teams            AS TeamA     ON compTeamA.idTeam = TeamA.idTeam
     JOIN TeamCompetitions AS compTeamB ON compTeamB.idTeamCompetition = Games.idTeamCompB
     JOIN Teams            AS TeamB     ON compTeamB.idTeam = TeamB.idTeam
     JOIN Competitions AS comp ON compTeamA.idCompetition = comp.idCompetition
```

An example:
Teams

```
1   Zimbabwe
2   Kenya
3   AJAX
4   Chelsea
5   Feyenoord
6   PEC Zwolle
```

Competitions

```
1   World Championship 2014
2   Dutch Premier League
```

TeamCompetitions

```
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   2   1
4   3   1
5   4   1
6   3   2
7   5   2
8   6   2
```

Games

```
1   2
2   3
7   6
7   8
```

Output of the query:

```
teamA   teamB   competition
Zimbabwe    Zimbabwe    World Championship 2014
Zimbabwe    Kenya   World Championship 2014
Feyenoord   AJAX    Dutch Premier League
Feyenoord   PEC Zwolle  Dutch Premier League
```

Hope this helps!